# Wordpress do_shortcode callback function

Tags: wordpress, callback

In wordpress, I utilize do_shortcode to call a form from Contact form 7 plugin like this

`echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="9866"]' );`

How can I set a callback function to this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the callback function?

Comment: I need to put a value in an hidden input, to pass some data to the mail; so I need to set that value when the shortcode is finished to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a callback function for `do_shortcode()`. If you need to call a function directly after, just call it directly. For example:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="9866"]' );
some_custom_function();
```

If instead you need to do something with the `return`ed value of `do_shortcode()`...don't `echo` it until you're ready:

```
$shortcode_contents = do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="9866"]' );
$altered_contents = alter_shortcode_contents_function( $shortcode_contents );
echo $altered_contents;
```

Comment: I was working on .val() instead .text() jquery function for the input text, that was the mistake...I thought the problem was that do_shortcode works asynchronous and that's why I was searching for callback...now the problem is closed, I mark your reply as best answer anyway

Comment: No, it does not work as you say. In fact do_shorcode() function don't return value, it just echo it.

Comment: @VipulHadiya , that's just wrong. Check out [the source code for `do_shortcode()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L202). It definitely `return`s a value.

Comment: @rnevius No, it is tested by me and I spend 3.5 hours to do that, without eco statement do_shortcode prints output. on http://smtkbpccs.edu.in/